# Extract multiple submatrices from a Tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm sorry that I've to ask this question, as it seems pretty straightforward, but I'm trying to find a way specifically in Tensorflow.

I've a Tensor matrix like below:

```
    [0 0 1 1]
X = [0 0 1 1]
    [1 1 0 0]
    [1 1 0 0]
```

I need to extract both patches:

```
  [1,1]     [1,1]
  [1,1] &   [1,1]
```

And I'm also give list of indices that point to the left element of submatrices given right above. E.g.

```
[[0,2]
 [2,0]]
```

I need to extract the patches in Tensorflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using tf.gather_nd as well. Below is an example showing all the working bits, and what you can do with gather_nd. You should be able to construct indices so that you only need a single gather_nd op to get all the submatrices you want. I just included the variable indices to show that you can use it to get submatrices from tensors you don't know ahead of time. So for example if you calculate some stuff in the graph and want to get submatrices based on that you could.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# build a tensor
x = np.arange(25)
x = np.reshape(x, [5, 5])
y = x + 4
three_d_array = np.stack([x, y], axis=2)
# just so you can see the shape its made of
print(np.all(x == three_d_array[:,:,0]))
print(np.all(y == three_d_array[:,:,1]))
# make it into a tf tensor
three_d_tensor = tf.constant(three_d_array)

# create a variable for tensor valued slice indices
row_0, col_0 = 0, 0
row_1, col_1 = 0, 1
row_2, col_2 = 1, 0
row_3, col_3 = 1, 1
slice_tensor = tf.constant([
    [row_0, col_0],
    [row_1, col_1],
    [row_2, col_2],
    [row_3, col_3]
])
slices = tf.Variable(initial_value=slice_tensor)

# op to get the sub matrices
gather_op = tf.gather_nd(three_d_tensor, slices)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess.run(init)

  submatrices = sess.run(gather_op)
  print(submatrices[0,:] == three_d_array[row_0, col_0])
  print(submatrices[1,:] == three_d_array[row_1, col_1])
  print(submatrices[2,:] == three_d_array[row_2, col_2])
  print(submatrices[3,:] == three_d_array[row_3, col_3])

  # shift down 2 along 2
  offset_top_left = tf.constant([2,2])
  update_variable_op = tf.assign(slices, slices + offset_top_left[None,:])
  sess.run(update_variable_op)
  submatrices = sess.run(gather_op)
  print(submatrices[0, :] == three_d_array[row_0 + 2, col_0 + 2])
  print(submatrices[1, :] == three_d_array[row_1 + 2, col_1 + 2])
  print(submatrices[2, :] == three_d_array[row_2 + 2, col_2 + 2])
  print(submatrices[3, :] == three_d_array[row_3 + 2, col_3 + 2])
```

Comment: @Ahsan Your welcome. If this was helpful could you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know what submatrices you need to extract, tf.slice() is the best choice.

The doc is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice)

For the example you presented, the solution with tf.slice() would be:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [[0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0]]
X = tf.Variable(x)
s1 = tf.slice(X, [2,0], [2,2])
s1 = tf.slice(X, [0,2], [2,2])


with tf.Session() as sess:
  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess.run(init)
  print(sess.run([s1, s1]))
```

This code renders the following result:

```
[array([[1, 1], [1, 1]], dtype=int32), 
array([[1, 1], [1, 1]], dtype=int32)]
```

**EDIT:**

For a more automatic and less verbose way, you can just use the [**getitem**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#__getitem__) proprety from tensorflow and slice it as you would slice a npArray.

The code could be something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

var = [[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0]]
X = tf.Variable(var)
slices = [[0,2], [2,0]]

s = []
for sli in slices:
  y = sli[0]
  x = sli[1]
  s.append(X[y:y+2, x:x+2])


with tf.Session() as sess:
  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess.run(init)
  print(sess.run(s))
```

This code renders the following result:

```
[array([[1, 1], [1, 1]], dtype=int32), 
array([[1, 1], [1, 1]], dtype=int32)]
```